# How to make Windows 7 ask for admin permission for all actions?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, firewall, uac

For example, Linux will ask permission for each and every action; e.g., for installing software and uninstalling software.

Is it possible to configure Windows like that?

Answer (score 2):

What Windows version you have?

In Windows 7, you can do it with User Account Control Settings: Go to Start Button, Control Panel (icon view), Action Center, then click Change User Account Control settings on the left side.

[image]

You have more information here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-user-account-control-settings#1TC=windows-7